# Can a Force-user from Star Wars use pyrokinesis?

Tags: star-wars

Now, I know that pyrokinesis is an actual thing in the *Star Wars* universe. I know that Force-users can manipulate fire to their advantage.

But can they do the "create fire out of nothing" type of pyrokinesis? Since Force-users can manipulate things on a molecular & subatomic level, I've been thinking that a Force-user can somehow generate fire from their hands if they're skilled enough at molecular manipulation. But I'm not sure.

Comment: If you can manipulate with the force on a molecular level, it would be very scary. Forget pyrokinesis. Thermonuclear heat would be where it's at. Just bring protection.

Comment: Yep. There's so much capabilities with molecular manipulation. I think it's just a bit difficult to do in the SW universe, but I suppose it can be mastered to be done easily. And to top it off; force-users from Star Wars can also manipulate things on a subatomic level, maybe even smaller than that.

Comment: Sort of? Lightining and electricity can cause fire.

Comment: Does rubbing two sticks together with the Force count?

Answer (score 4):

Within the main canon there don't appear to be any examples of this, although Wookieepedia does label Palpatine's energy rope thing as "[fiery energy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fiery_energy)". It seems highly debatable whether this counts or.

Within the EU we see this power on multiple occasions.

**Leia uses the Force to light some candles in [*Children of the Jedi*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Jedi_(novel)).**

> She hit the light switch by the bed. Nothing happened. In a panic of
> confusion **her mind reached out**, groped for the candles that had
> illuminated the room earlier with such soft, romantic light. Luke had
> taught her…
>
> **Fire sprang to life** again on the floating wicks.

**The Nightsisters of Dathomir show the ability to create balls of flame in [*Fate of the Jedi - Backlash*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fate_of_the_Jedi:_Backlash), suggesting it's a *general* Force power rather than one aligned to either side.**

> Dresdema turned back toward the shuttles, dropping her spear, **her
> hands weaving a spell of flame** that she intended for the man who dared
> try to trick her.

**And we see how this trick is done in [*The Crystal Star*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Crystal_Star)**

> She imagined the molecules of air all around her. She imagined one
> molecule. She imagined it moving, faster and faster. She felt the
> molecule respond.
>
> Hethrir’s power did not react. She knew it was around her, she could
> feel its attention off in the distance. But it did not notice the tiny
> motion she created.
>
> She added another molecule, another, doubling and redoubling the
> number she affected. Soon a small handful of air vibrated with her
> energy. Its warmth took the chill from her cell.
>
> **The swirl of air glowed red, then yellow, spreading light into the
> corners of Jaina’s cell.**

Answer (score 1):

**Star Wars: The Clone Wars:**

In the episode "Massacre," Nightsister Mother Talzin waves her hand and appears to start a fire from apparently nothing.

[image]

[image]

[image]